# Combination of adapter and template views in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

I just want to start off by saying the list view works fine, there's no problem with this code.

All I want to know is how I can expand on it. I want to have a label (a bit of text to describe what the items in the list view represent) at the top of the list view before all of the items from the adapter appear. But obviously, because I want it *inside* the list view I want the label to go out of view when the user starts scrolling through the list.

How do I achieve that?

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_task_summary);
TasksSummaryListViewHelper adapter = new TasksSummaryListViewHelper(this, getTasks());
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.text_empty_list));
```

And my template:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_task_summary"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="15sp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_task_summary_selector_unselected">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom List `Adapter` , When `getView` is called, create a title view for position 0 and other position you own list item layout

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View contentView , ViewGroup parent){
    View row = null;

    if(position == 0) {
            // inflate any custom layout or just a textView
            TextView titleView = new TextView();
             titleView.setText("TITLE");
            row = titleView;
        }
        else {
            row = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
    return row;
 }
```

And ,You will see the recyle issue with `ListView` since it uses the same child view for other items,

So to that you need to `Override` the `getViewTypeCount` and return the view type count as 2

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Also, `Override` `getItemViewType` and return a unique id for position 0 and other views same id.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    // return a unique number
    if(position == 0){
        return 0; 
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other way? Ideally I don't want to have to do it directly in the adapter.

Comment: I believe this is the best approach. Other way is you can place an view above `ListView` , but you won't able to scroll the view with `ListView`

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have tried this, but now it is removing the final element of the list view? So before, I had 4 list view items - now I am only seeing the Title + the first 3 list view items. So it's cutting off the final item. What do I need to do to fix that? Thanks

Comment: Override getCount and return 4+1 or add an first empty item in your adapter list object which holds data

Answer (score 1):

You can do as Libin suggests, but if it's one static view that needs to scroll with the rest of the list, I think it's better to use `listView.addHeaderView()` instead. This way you don't need to make any changes to your adapter at all. Note that the position reported in any OnListItemClickListeners will be offset by the number of header views.

Comment: I wish I knew about this earlier :(